# The routes stacks up on each other

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, gatsby

I am working with Material UI and I am using Link component prop to define the routes . I have multiple routes like

```
/home 
/contact
/login
```

But when I am clicking on /home then /contact so it goes to /home/contact instead of /contact . How can I fix this issue so my page goes to /contact instead of stacking up on previous route .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by a missing forward slash (`/`) at the beginning of your link's component `slug`.

Your `Link` component should be:

```
<Link to="/contact">
```

Instead of

```
<Link to="contact">
```

Assuming a dynamic link generation add it as template literal:

```
<Link to={`/${someSlugVariable}`}>
```

This behavior (the concatenation of slugs) is expected when dealing with partials/relative URLs, it works, in the same way, using anchors (`<a>`) that it's output in the end.

Comment: Thank you so much , I don't know how I didn't realize it